# Convert form from CNF to DNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I have a few question about converting forms to DNF, CNF and from CNF to DNF.

1) How can I convert this to DNF $(p \vee q) \wedge (q \vee \neg r) $

2) How can I convert this to CNF $(p \wedge q) \vee (q \wedge\neg r)$

3) Is there any fast way to convert one form from CNF to DNF or DNF to CNF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
1.\quad (p\vee q)\wedge (q\vee\neg r) = q\wedge(p\vee q) \vee\neg r\wedge(p\vee q) = q \vee \neg r p\vee \neg rq = q\vee p\neg r
$$
$$
2. \quad (p\wedge q)\vee (q\wedge\neg r) = q(p\vee\neg r)
$$

Comment: Could you explain which rules you used to make form like this?

Comment: @hadson172, I used: $a\wedge(b\vee c) = a\wedge b\vee a\wedge c$ (and vise versa), $a\wedge a = a$, $a\wedge (a\vee b)=a$.

Answer (score 1):

This is mechanized in Maple. For example,

```
with(Logic):
Export(Normalize(`&and`(`&or`(p, q), `&or`(q, `&not`(r))))), form = DNF));
```

$$ p \land q \lor p \land \neg r \lor q \lor q \land \neg r
  $$
See [?Logic](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Logic) for info.

PS. It should be noted that the original Maple input is not exactly represented in the above code.